# Looking for Star/Sky/Constellation map library

Tags: library, javascript

I am looking for a particular library that many shops use for rendering how the sky looked at a certain date/time/location. In the links down below you can see that everyone has the same sky which moves and acts the same with given parameters. So I assume that there is a library but I can't find it...

For example:

https://starmap.modernmapart.com/

https://thestarposter.com/editor#/

https://magicalnightsky.com/editor/

https://create.thenightsky.com/en/design?tnscc=HR&_ga=2.258955210.1932977591.1612552404-1890876991.1608334485&_gac=1.93425391.1612552405.CjwKCAiA9vOABhBfEiwATCi7GPtJ4re3FhRlbbNoTZduiAeJLSiBNnTBPDnELTiqMwiQeRboas1UpRoCW28QAvD_BwE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the library, if anyone else also needs it. It is d3-celestial (https://www.npmjs.com/package/d3-celestial). To get the round view, under the config set projection parameter to "airy".

Comment: Thanks Stejpan for updating up on what you found.  Can you add a source URL for the library to your answer, as well as any other details? Thanks, and welcome!